# Encrypt data using private key in C and decrypting data using public key in Java

Tags: java, c, encryption, rsa

I have use case where i want to to encrypt some data using private key in C and decrypt it using public key in java.

I generated the the public/private key using openssl. I am able to run a c code for encrypting the data using private key.

Something like following code :

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

char * data;
char *encrypted;

FILE * fp = fopen(<private_key_file>,"rb");
RSA *rsa= RSA_new() ;
rsa = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
RSA_private_encrypt(data_len,data,encrypted,rsa,padding);
```

This works fine and i am also able to decrypt it using public key in C. I am not able to decrypt the same using public key in Java. For this, I converted the public key to DER format :
    `$ openssl rsa -in private_key.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public_key.der`

I am using following code

```
public String decrypt(byte[] encrypted) throws Exception
{
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");

    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

    byte[] encKey = readFromFile(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE, false);

    X509EncodedKeySpec ks = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);

    PublicKey pk = kf.generatePublic(ks);

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);

    byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

    return new String(plainText,"UTF-8");
}
```

I get the following exception with my java code.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:356)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2121)
at AssyncKeyEncryptTest.decrypt(AssyncKeyEncryptTest.java:198)
at AssyncKeyEncryptTest.test(AssyncKeyEncryptTest.java:45)
at AssyncKeyEncryptTest.main(AssyncKeyEncryptTest.java:32)
```

Can someone please help me in fixing the error in decrypting the data using public key in java ?

Comment: That's not how RSA works. You encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key.

Comment: Perhaps you want to sign using the private key and verify using the public key.

Comment: RSA algorithm for encryption and decryption is the same, so you can encrypt with private key, and decrypt with public. This is used for digital signature. You should not encrypt more than one packet with the private key for secure reasons.

Comment: Most high level RSA tools/API do not allow you to run private encryption/decryption. You may need to search for a different and custom RSA implementation for the Java side.

Comment: @JonatanGoebel, you can encrypt (using the same words than you used: sign) whatever number of packets you want with the private key.  As you said, you are signing them, so they can be unencrypted(verified) with the public key without risk.  What's not recommended is to use the same key both to sing and encrypt messages (or even worse, to sign and encrypt the same plaintext) as the key module can be compromised by this.

Answer (score 2):

The stacktrace suggests different padding between encryption and decryption.

Try "PKCS1Padding" as instance for decryption as you used it while encrypting.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` instead of `"RSA"`.
If you are unable to find a `Cipher` instance with `"RSA/None/PKCS1Padding"` then try adding a security provider like Bouncy Castle Provider.
`Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());`
Adding the bouncy castle dependency should be straightforward enough.

http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html